# Writing & formatting word document using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a word document using excel VBA.  I can create a word doc, write text to it, change styles not a problem.  What I want to do is center some text, I cant for the life of me figure it out.  Here is the code I'm using to write the doc:

```
   Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = False

    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add

    'Set up page settings
    With wrdApp.ActiveDocument.PageSetup
        .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
        .TopMargin = wrdApp.InchesToPoints(0.98)
        .BottomMargin = wrdApp.InchesToPoints(0.98)
        .LeftMargin = wrdApp.InchesToPoints(0.98)
        .RightMargin = wrdApp.InchesToPoints(0.98)
    End With
    'End set up page settings

    With wrdDoc
        .Styles.Add ("SHeading")
        .Styles.Add ("StdText")

        With .Styles("SHeading").Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 14
            .Bold = False
            .Underline = True
        End With
        With .Styles("StdText").Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 8
            .Bold = False
            .Underline = False
        End With
    End With
    wrdApp.Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    wrdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
    wrdApp.Selection.Style = wrdDoc.Styles("SHeading")
    wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:="Text Line 1"


    wrdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
    wrdApp.Selection.Style = wrdDoc.Styles("StdText")
    wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:="Text Line 2: "
    wrdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
```

All I want to do is center the "Text Line 1" text.  I have googled and tried all sorts of solutions to no avail.

Any ideas out there?

UPDATE:
Sort it - it was as simple as needing the MS Word Object Library reference selected in VBA, then the centering works fine!

Comment: Try recording a macro while centering existing text in Word and see what Word uses.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [Alignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197202%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property of the ParagraphFormat object of the Style.

```
wrdDoc.Styles("SHeading").ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

It must be one of the [WdParagraphAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdparagraphalignment%28v=office.11%29.aspx) enumerations.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it makes no difference.  It doesn't bring up an error, it just doesn't center the text. Am I doing something wrong with the assignment of the style or paragraph creation?

Comment: Once I added the reference in vba for ms word then this answer works great.

Comment: I did not even consider that the constants do not work in the other Office applications.  Furthermore, the documentation does not specify what numbers the constants represent.  Sometimes I find myself opening the target application and MsgBoxing the constants just to see what they actually mean, like so: MsgBox wdAlignParagraphCenter.  In this case, wdAlignParagraphCenter means 1.  Thus, you could also set the the Alignment to 1 and it would do what you intended without adding the Word reference.

Comment: This is yet another reason to add `Option Explicit` to the top of existing modules and check Require Variable Declaration in the IDE's Tools->Options screen. If you have this turned on, you'd see which constants are not being resolved instead of having the silently interpretted as zeroes.