# Trying to web scrape from website into excel, then convert into word doc

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

So I have been assigned to scrape some information off of a website. The information is pretty heavy, and I need to click individual "read more" buttons in order to get the full information. After I click "read more" I then need to go back into the previous page, click "read more" on the second item. Then rinse and repeat until I have all information I need. Once I have all the information, it then needs to be converted into a word document.

1. Navigate to URL, I know how to do that
2. Click "button" that said read more, The problem with that is there are over 70 buttons that say "read more" and I don't know how to differentiate between them
3. Once I have all information, scrape several pieces of information, how do I get it to excel??
4. Once information gathered into excel, how do I convert it into word?

Code example:

```
'Bring IE up and navigate to page
      Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
      ie.Visible = True
      'Set the URL
      strURL = "my url"
      'Navigate to url
      ie.Navigate strURL
      'Wait for the page to show up
```

button.click?

I am fairly new to Vba's excel option, I'm sure there are easier ways, but this is the way I am supposed to do it. Any help or tips are greatly appreciated.

The URL is https://www.legacy.com/obituaries/commercialappeal/browse

Comment: without the url, it's difficult to help. But in your case, I would do a Loop to check all buttons and try to get the one you want comparing the class attribute or something else. Check the HTML code, because there must be something that helps you to identify that button as unique.

Comment: Heres the website https://www.legacy.com/obituaries/commercialappeal/browse I need to press each view obituary button and extract the full description

Comment: I examined the code a bit further, I believe what dignifies the separation of obituary buttons would be "data react Id" but I think they're constantly changing with updates to each different death

Comment: There are links connected to each obituary button. So, first parse those relevant links and then create http request to each of those links using `xmlhttp` request. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

So this was trickier than expected as I had problems getting the whole results set. In the end I went with [selenium basic](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/) as it handled the initial page load better and I didn't get repeated warnings about cookies and the like. To be honest that may be because I used Chrome Driver! The driver can be changed of course so another supported browser type.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

'281 Results on 2018-05-04 '16:00
Public Sub test()

    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .Get "https://www.legacy.com/obituaries/commercialappeal/browse?view=name"

        Dim elements  As List
        Set elements = d.FindElementsByTag("a").Attribute("href")

        Dim hrefCollection As New Collection, i As Long

        For i = 1 To elements.Count
            If InStr(elements(i), "https://www.legacy.com/obituaries/commercialappeal/obituary.aspx?n=") > 0 Then
                If i = 1 Then
                    hrefCollection.Add elements(i)
                ElseIf i > 1 And elements(i) <> elements(i - 1) Then
                    hrefCollection.Add elements(i)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Dim wrdApp As Object, wrdDoc As Object
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True

    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add

    With wrdApp.ActiveDocument.PageSetup
        .Orientation = 1                         'wdOrientLandscape
        .TopMargin = wrdApp.InchesToPoints(0.98)
        .BottomMargin = wrdApp.InchesToPoints(0.98)
        .LeftMargin = wrdApp.InchesToPoints(0.98)
        .RightMargin = wrdApp.InchesToPoints(0.98)
    End With

    With wrdDoc
        .Styles.Add ("SHeading")
        .Styles.Add ("StdText")

        With .Styles("SHeading").Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 14
            .Bold = False
            .Underline = True
        End With
        With .Styles("StdText").Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 8
            .Bold = False
            .Underline = False
        End With
    End With

    wrdApp.Selection.Collapse Direction:=0       'wdCollapseEnd

    For i = 1 To 2                               '<== Test example to get two results
        DoEvents
        wrdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
        wrdApp.Selection.Style = wrdDoc.Styles("SHeading")
        wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=GetInfo(hrefCollection.Item(i), d)
    Next i

    '   For Each Item In hrefCollection  ''<== use this above to get all results
    '       DoEvents
    '       wrdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
    '       wrdApp.Selection.Style = wrdDoc.Styles("SHeading")
    '       wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=GetInfo(hrefCollection.Item(i), d)
    '   Next Item

    d.Quit
End Sub

Public Function GetInfo(ByVal url As String, ByVal d As WebDriver) As String
    With d
        .Get url
        GetInfo = d.FindElementByClass("ObitTextContent").Text
    End With
End Function
```

**Note:**

1. I am not going to show the output as not sure obituaries need to be on this site.
2. Credit to [@Kyo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569182/writing-formatting-word-document-using-excel-vba?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) who's Word code I hijacked. You will need to tidy this into what you need.